# Python code not appending 'Free Period' when I want it to

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

```
list1 = []

elective = []
prereq = []

someNumber = 1

dict2 = {
1: SEM2period1, 2: SEM2period2,
2: SEM2period3, 4: SEM2period4,
5: SEM2period5, 6: SEM2period6,
7: SEM2period7, 8: SEM2period8
}


for key, dlist in dict2.items():
    if not dlist:
        list1.append("Free Period")
        someNumber += 1
        continue
    for item in dlist:
        if item in list1:
            continue
        elif item in elective:
            elecStorage.append(item)
        elif item in prereq:
            list1.append(item)
            someNumber += 1
            break
        if someNumber > len(list1):
            for index in elecStorage:
                if index in list1:
                    break
                else:
                    list1.append(index)
                    someNumber += 1
                    elecStorage[:] = []
                    break
```

Notes: Electives and Prereq both contain strings like "Calculus 1" (for prereq), or "Astronomy" (for elective.) The variables in dict2 are lists that contain class (as in classroom) names that were called earlier by the function.

What the snippet that starts out with "for key, dlist in dict2.items()" should do is search through the the elements of the first list, checking first if there is a list, if there isn't then append "Free Period" into the list. Then it should check if any of the elements of the list exist in prereq, and finally if there isn't, append something from electives into it. (Because if it gets past the first condition, it's safe to assume there is at least an elective.) and then loop back around and perform the same operation to the next list of elements.

Issue is, unless all of the lists contain nothing, it won't append 'Free Period' and I can't figure out why.

Ideas?

Comment: What type of object is SEM2periodX specifically when there is no list. Is it something like "None"?

Comment: It would be None, yeah.

Comment: Can you verify that SEM?period? is really None, and not something like an empty list, in the case where there is at least one non-empty list?  a '[print x for x in dict2.values()]' should help debug.

Comment: Oh heck, It's returning as [], not None.

Comment: But even if it's returning as [] it shouldn't matter, correct?

Comment: It absolutely does matter. [] is an empty list object, None is nothing (like NULL in C).  The correct check for an empty list is 'if list1 == []' or 'if len(list1) == 0'.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your SEM*period* is likely returning an empty list, and not None.  The correct checks for empty list '[]', is  'if list1 == []' or 'if len(list1) == 0'.

None is placeholder meaning a non-existing object.  [] is a valid list object, it just has no entries in the list.  'if not foo' is simply checking for None, not an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify the contents of your SEM2period variables, this is hard to diagnose without them.  I didn't follow the rest of your logic, but it's really just the first block in the loop that you are interested in, yes?  You may have a list containing an empty list, perhaps? That would mess up your logic:

```
d2 = {1:['elec'], 2:[]}

for key, dlist in d2.items():
    if not dlist:
        print 'empty!'
    else:
        print dlist
```

gives you

```
['elec']
empty!
```

but

```
d2 = {1:['elec'], 2:[[]]}

for key, dlist in d2.items():
    if not dlist:
        print 'empty!'
    else:
        print dlist
```

gives you

```
['elec']
[[]]
```